# How to autoplay HTML5 embedded player?

Tags: html

I want to autoplay my online radio but can't seem to fixed it.

Autoplay="true" autoplay="1" doesnt work

I got this shortcode

```
[html5radio radiolink="http://server:port/" radiotype="shoutcast" bcolor="000000" image="" title="Stream Title" artist="Stream Artist" facebook="http://www.facebook.com/radioforgecom" twitter="http://twitter.com/radioforgecom"]
```

and this

```
< iframe src="https://player.radioforge.com/v2/shoutcast.html?radiolink=http://server:port/&radiotype=shoutcast&bcolor=000000&image=&facebook=http://www.facebook.com/radioforgecom&twitter=http://twitter.com/radioforgecom&title=Stream Title&artist=Stream Artist" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" width="367" height="227"></iframe>
```

After trying codes that I can think of, the video is still not autoplaying.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-playing audio is something that browsers are trying to do away with. In order for audio to be allowed to play, the user must first interact with the page in some way. See [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) about Chrome’s autoplay policy.

Comment: So autoplay won't work? I really needed it since my wordpress site is an online radio.

Comment: I think your users will understand if they just need to click a big play button to start the radio.